# React Native - How to Disable Display Size on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am looking to disable Display Size scaling on Android. I have been able to sort out text size scaling by using `allowFontScaling={false}` but I cannot find a way to do the same for display size. When display size is increased, all my Views get mashed together making the app impossible to use.

There is the same question with no answer here:

> [React Native - Disable "Screen Size" Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738203/react-native-disable-screen-size-setting)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, this is a legit hard problem to work around. You can use the screen dimensions to scale everything, but that is granular to each view. Something cross-cutting would be nice.

Comment: I am running into this issue too! created a [RN Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24933)

Comment: Any success? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Would love to see a solution to this.  No valid answers exist online and it is a major problem for many applications in the Google Play Store, even from larger-scale businesses