# React Native: Design disturb after increasing Accessibility Larger Size

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

facing the issue for FontSize when the user increases accessibility size. wanted to prevent the setting "Accessibility" or "Display size". for that I have tried with

```
    if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false
```

But unable to succeed. There was also issue with `alert` and `TextInput`

current react native version:

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.2",
```

also gone through:

1. [React Native - Disable "Screen Size" Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738203/react-native-disable-screen-size-setting)
2. [How to disable font scaling in React Native for IOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app/51414341)

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

With TextInput try this :

```js
 TextInput.defaultProps = {
      ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}), // Tắt Scaling ở TextInput (Resize text )
      allowFontScaling: false,
    };
```